# Cello double stop

Tags: cello, double-stops

Just want to make sure this is possible.  As you can tell, it's styled after Pachelbel's "Canon," but it's in G.  I'm sure it would have to be somewhat detached, and, wherever possible, an open string is used.

[image]

Comment: How good a cellist?  The minor third requires stretching beyond usual finger positions, though most adults can do it.  Any cellist who isn't near-professional level will have some trouble with intonation without a good deal of practice.

Comment: I was writing for a mature string quartet--college-plus--and these 4 measures would be a solo.  Furthermore, it's repeated another 3 times in the intro (building the Pachelbel theme until it segues into a pop song intro.  So, with that many times, would it get awkward?  I can't write it lower due to low-interval-limits and I wanted the voice-leading it has, so could assign the upper notes to the viola if I had to, although I felt that would detract from the novelty of the figure.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit awkward but can be done.  And no, you don't have to indicate open strings.  The player can easily figure that out.